# Encoding error when opening an Excel file with python xlrd module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have some excel files with extensions that are xls，when I use xlrd to open these files, it failed，I do not know how to solve it.

```py
    oldbook=xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls')
    oldsheet=oldbook.sheets()[0]

PS C:\Users\我是猫\Desktop\python> python -u "c:\Users\我是猫\Desktop\python\a.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\我是猫\Desktop\python\a.py", line 64, in <module>
        oldbook=xlrd.open_workbook(result)
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
        ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 117, in open_workbook_xls
        bk.parse_globals()
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1209, in parse_globals
        self.handle_format(data)
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\formatting.py", line 538, in handle_format
        unistrg = unpack_unicode(data, 2)
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\biffh.py", line 284, in unpack_unicode
        strg = unicode(rawstrg, 'utf_16_le')
      File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py", line 31, in <lambda>
        unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
      File "E:\python\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
        return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: illegal encoding
    PS C:\Users\我是猫\Desktop\python>
```

Comment: Can you give us the file.xls ?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the encoding used:

```
oldbook = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls', encoding_override="cp1252")
```

You can also try `encoding_override="utf-8"`, play around with the encoding till you get the right one.